# Как правильно экспортировать файлы js внутри webpack?

Tags: javascript, webpack, ecmascript-6

У меня пока что два файла, они лежат в одной папке js,
Файл validate.js - внутри него находится класс с валидатором
и основной файл index.js который билдиться потом в common.js

будет ещё файл, их всех нужно подключить внутри webpack в файл index.js

Как правильно это сделать?

Comment: Вот пример https://github.com/mihdan/cyr2lat/tree/master/src

Comment: по этому примеру не понятно, есть ещё примеры?